# Python running script when it shouldn't

Tags: python, bash

The script bellow gets the reading from a thermometer every second and works just fine.

I have been trying to add additional functionality to this.  So when a certain temperature is reached, it executes a script.  In this case if temp is bellow 20, run heaton script.  If above 20, run heatoff script.

The issue I am having is that when the temperature is bellow 20, it runs heaton script fine.  Once it gets above 20 and I want to run the heatoff script, it runs it.  Once the entire program starts again, it seems to run the heaton script even if above 20 and then runs the heatoff.

This means when above 20, it runs heatoff then heaton in a loop until the temperature does actually fall bellow 20 then it only runs heat on.

```
import threading
import time
import os

def hot_temp():
    with open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0216019bb8ff/w1_slave") as tfile:
        next(tfile)
        secondline = next(tfile)
    temperaturedata = secondline.split(" ")[9] 
    temperature = float(temperaturedata[2:]) 
    temperature = temperature / 1000 
    if temperature < 20.000:
        os.system("sudo python /var/www/html/scripts/heaton.py")
    else:
        os.system("sudo python /var/www/html/scripts/heatoff.py")
    return temperature

while True:
    output = hot_temp()    
    with open('/var/www/html/output/hottemp.html', 'w') as f:
        print >> f, output
    time.sleep(1)
```

I've also tried using `else` instead of `elif` but I get exactly the same result.

```
    temperature = temperature / 1000 
if temperature < 20.000:
    os.system("sudo python /var/www/html/scripts/heaton.py")
elif temperature > 20.000:
    os.system("sudo python /var/www/html/scripts/heatoff.py")
return temperature
```

I have also tried changing temp ranges, so that heaton until 20.000 and heatoff at 20.000 or 20.001 or 20.010 or 20.100

Comment: did you add print statements before and after `if` line to see if indeed the temp is > 20 and it still gets inside the if branch?

Comment: Yup just tried that it's fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved when I changed `< 20.000` and `> 20.000` to `<= 20.000` and `>= 20.000`.

```
import threading
import datetime
import time
import os

def hot_temp():
    with open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0216019bb8ff/w1_slave") as tfile:
        next(tfile)
        secondline = next(tfile)
    temperaturedata = secondline.split(" ")[9] 
    temperature = float(temperaturedata[2:]) 
    temperature = temperature / 1000 
    if temperature <= 20.000:
        os.system("sudo python /var/www/html/scripts/heaton.py")
        output = temperature
        with open('/var/www/html/log.txt', 'a') as f:
            print >> f, datetime.datetime.now().time(), "Current Temp: ", output, " (HEATING)"
    elif temperature >= 20.000:
        os.system("sudo python /var/www/html/scripts/heatoff.py")
        output = temperature
        with open('/var/www/html/log.txt', 'a') as f:
            print >> f, datetime.datetime.now().time(), "Current Temp: ", output, "(COOLING)"
    elif temperature >= 30.000:
        os.system("sudo python /var/www/html/scripts/mailheaton.py")
    elif temperature <= 10.000:
        os.system("sudo python /var/www/html/scripts/mailheatoff.py")
    return temperature

while True:
    output = hot_temp()    
    with open('/var/www/html/output/hottemp.html', 'w') as f:
        print >> f, output
    time.sleep(1)
```